# Spring data specification inner join subquery

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

I have a project written in spring boot version 1.5.x with a connection to a MariaDB database and several tables with a large amount of relationships between them. To query the database I am using the JpaSpecificationExecutor interface provided in org.springframework.data.jpa.repository. The reason we use specifications is to build dynamic queries without having to write a new query for every filter possibility in the repository itself. In the entities themselves, every relationship has the Lazy fetchtype. Also the fetching of the relationships is dynamical and is not the same every time, I also define in the specification what has to be fetched.

Because we have a large dataset, we implemented paging, also using the methods provided by the JpaSpecificationExecutor interface. Now I noticed that everytime I ask to fetch a OneToMany relationship to be fetched, the paging executes in memory and not in the database, the limit gets dropped from the query. This behavior can be expected, but now I am searching for a workaround. Please consider the example below:

For example we have 3 tables: Person, Role and Title. Every person can have multiple roles and multiple titles. One way we where thinking to solve our issue was by using following query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Person p
        JOIN
    Role r on r.f_person = p.id
        JOIN
    Title t on t.f_person = p.id
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        p2.id
    FROM
        Person p2
    WHERE
        p2.name LIKE '%John%'
    ORDER BY p2.name DESC
    LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100) AS p2 ON p2.id = p.id
```

Is there any way to build this query in a specification or by using the entitymanger so that we can keep dynamic nature of our queries.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this ticket about Hibernate:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3356

This tells me that the functionality that I am looking for, will not work with Hibernate for now. I split our query in to 2 parts, one that gets the ID's of all the entities which is paged and sorted, then I fetch all the entities based on those ID's. Probably not the most performant solution, but it works and is a hell of a lot faster then no paging at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to give Blaze-Persistence a shot for this as it will generate efficient pagination queries. Blaze-Persistence is a query builder API built on top of JPA with support for advanced DBMS features. Pagination-wise it is very mighty and also supports keyset pagination and has some other tricks up its slieve.

Thanks to the spring data integration, you only need to configure it: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

Apart from that, I can only recommend you to take a look into using Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views on top of this to further improve performance. You can even do dynamic fetching if you want: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#fetching-a-data-subset

From what I have read, you'd probably benefit the most from the [GraphQL integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#usage-4).